# Allocating memory for a Structure in C

Tags: c, malloc, structure

I'm tasked to create a program which dynamically allocates memory for a structure.
normally we would use

```
x=malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
```

However, what do I use for a structure variable?
I don't think its possible to do

```
struct st x = malloc(sizeof(struct));
```

Could someone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: @Blackbinary: Almost there. The correct syntax is `malloc(sizeof(struct st))`. Of course `sizeof *x` stated below is preferred.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

My favorite:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct st *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Note that:

- `x` must be a pointer
- no cast is required
- include appropriate header

Comment: Don't let kids play with sharp objects :)

Comment: The thing I like the most is the fact that even if you rename the structure later, the RHS still works. Arguably, with modern editors this is not much of a problem.

Comment: Awesome. No more malloc( sizeof( struct foo ) ) for me... :) (great user name also)

Comment: Won't RHS lead you to trouble if you do a typo error and miss *? I always thought instead of doing *x mentioning the struct name is a better way as it will protect against the typo error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jay: Certainly, but that is just one of the many subtle ways in which you can inject bugs. I have read (and suffered) from forgetting to change the `struct` name on the RHS much more. Another counter-point: read my first bulleted item or David Thornley's comment.

Comment: @dirkgently
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
 int x;
};

void main()
{
 struct A *st = malloc(sizeof *st); 
}

I got this error when running on Visual C++ 6.0: "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'struct A *'
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast"

Answer (score 7):

You're not quite doing that right.  `struct st x` is a structure, not a pointer.  It's fine if you want to allocate one on the stack.  For allocating on the heap, `struct st * x = malloc(sizeof(struct st));`.

Answer (score 5):

It's exactly possible to do that - and is the correct way

Assuming you meant to type

```
struct st *x = malloc(sizeof(struct st));
```

ps. You have to do sizeof(struct) even when you know the size of all the contents because the compiler may pad out the struct so that memebers are aligned.

```
struct tm {
  int x;
  char y;
}
```

might have a different size to

```
struct tm {
  char y;
  int x;
}
```

Comment: Nope:  `sizeof(struct)` is not legal.  `sizeof(struct st)` is.

Comment: you mean `struct st *x = malloc(sizeof(struct st));`  struct itself doesn't actually have a size.

Comment: Sorry - skimmed reading the op.
I was concentrating on them asking if sizeof(any struct) was legal

Comment: Is is `struct st` or `struct tm`? :-)

Answer (score 5):

`struct st* x = malloc( sizeof( struct st ));`

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
struct st *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct st *x = (struct st *)malloc(sizeof(struct st));`

Comment: Do not cast `malloc()`: 1. It's not needed (C void* is different than C++ void*), 2. Lint-like analysis tools could detect giving malloc() the wrong size, and 3. including the proper header will give the compiler the right hints that you mean the *system* malloc, which may produce better code.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, when you call `sizeof` on a `struct` type, C recursively calls sizeof on the fields of the `struct`.  So, `struct st *x = malloc(sizeof(struct st));` only really works if `struct st` has a fixed size.  This is only significant if you have something like a variable sized string in your struct and you DON'T want to give it the max length each time.

In general,

```
struct st *x = malloc(sizeof(struct st));
```

works.  Occasionally, you will run into either variable sized structs or 'abstract' structs (think: abstract class from Java) and the compiler will tell you that it cannot determine the size of struct st.  In these cases, Either you will have to calculate the size by hand and call malloc with a number, or you will find a function which returns a fully implemented and malloc'd version of the struct that you want.

Comment: AFAIK in C there's no such a thing as variable sized structs or abstract structs (you can fake them, but they are not supported at language level); the only case in which the compiler will tell you that it doesn't know the size of a struct is when the struct is only declared but not defined (useful if in the current compilation unit you just handle pointers to the struct).