# Defining a Structure in C with Malloc

Tags: c, memory, malloc, structure

I asked a [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177391/allocating-memory-for-a-structure-in-c) on defining a structure using malloc.
This was the answer I was given by the majority:

```
struct retValue* st = malloc(sizeof(*st));
```

I was showing a friend my code, and we came to a stumbling block.
Could someone please explain why this code works? 
From my viewpoint, *st hasn't been defined when you malloc it, so there could be any kind of garbage in there. It should be `malloc(sizeof(struct retValue))`

Thanks for any help

Comment: You answered your own question. sizeof(struct retValue) is correct

Comment: Sorry, the question was not 'Is this correct, or what is correct?' it was 'Why does this work?'

Comment: It might help understanding if you change the terminology. You aren't *defining* a structure using malloc, you're *allocating* a structure using malloc. You're defining `st`, which is a pointer (not a struct). That pointer is already defined and available for use in the initialiser expression (on the RHS of the equals sign), it just doesn't have a value, so most uses would be invalid. This one's OK, though, because sizeof doesn't use the value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sizeof looks at the type of the expression given to it, it does not evaluate the expression. Thus, you only need to make sure that the variables used in the expression are declared so that the compiler can deduce their type.

In your example, st is already declared as pointer-to-struct-retValue. Consequently the compiler is able to deduce the type of the expression "*st".

Although it doesn't look like it is already declared in your code, the compiler has already taken care of it for you. All declarations in your code are moved to the beginning of the block in which they occur by the compiler. Suppose you write

One way to illustrate the knowledge that is available to the compiler is to look at the intermediate output it generates. Consider this example code...

```
struct retValue {long int a, long int b};
...
printf("Hello World!\n");
struct retValue* st = malloc(sizeof(*st));
```

Using gcc as an example and teh above code in the *main()* function of *test.c*, let's look at the intermediate output by running...

```
gcc -fdump-tree-cfg test.c
```

The compiler will generate the file *test.c.022t.cfg* - Look at it and you'll see

```
[ ... removed internal stuff ...]
;; Function main (main)

Merging blocks 2 and 3
main (argc, argv)
{
  struct retValue * st;
  int D.3097;
  void * D.3096;

  # BLOCK 2
  # PRED: ENTRY (fallthru)
  __builtin_puts (&"Hello World!"[0]);
  D.3096 = malloc (16);
  st = (struct retValue *) D.3096;
  D.3097 = 0;
  return D.3097;
  # SUCC: EXIT

}
```

Note how the declaration was moved to the beginning of the block and the argument to malloc is already replaced with the actual value denoting the size of the type the expression evaluated to. As pointed out in the comments, the fact that the declaration was moved to the top of the block is an implementation detail of the compiler. However, the fact that the compiler is able to do this and also to insert the correct size into the malloc all shows that the compiler was able to deduce the necessary information from the input.

I personally prefer to give the actual type name as a parameter to sizeof, but that is probably a question of coding-style where I'd say that consistency trumps personal-preference.

Comment: His question was about `*st` doing "bad things".  `*st` is invalid if `st` doesn't point to valid data.  But since `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its argument, it's okay to use `*st` as an operand to `sizeof`, even if `st` is `NULL` for example.

Comment: Actually, the question was "how/why does it work despite the fact that st cannot be dereferenced at the time malloc needs to know how much space to allocate"...

Comment: Putting a declaration at the beginning of the block in the parsed version of the code is an implementation detail. The compiler isn't required to do it, even though yours happens to, and the questioner's code works whether the compiler does it or not. The following code doesn't compile, showing that the declaration isn't "really" moved: `sizeof(*st); char *st = 0;`.

Comment: In addition to what Steve Jessop said, let me add that it isn't code rearrangement that determines if the `sizeof` works but rather a declaration/definition _in scope_. Your answer ascribes standard behavior incorrectly to an implementation detail.

Comment: I have rephrased the answer so that it no longer emphasizes the reordering as the reason but only as an example for what the compiler is able to deduce from the input. Thanks for your feedback guys.

Answer (score 19):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't actually evaluate its operand - it just looks at its type. This is done at compile time rather than runtime. So it can safely be performed before the variable has been assigned.

Comment: I think i understand. So your saying `sizeof` looks at *st and says 'Oh thats a pointer!' and then allocates enough memory for a pointer. It doesn't care what *st is actually holding. Right?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. `*st` means "the thing that st points to", so the compiler returns the size of the structure, not the size of the pointer.

Comment: @Blackbinary: Close: `st` is a pointer, but `*st` is a struct. So it looks at `*st` and says "Oh that's a `struct retValue`!" and then allocates enough memory for a retValue structure. The actual contents of `*st` don't matter.

Comment: Ah, so close. thanks. Must've just got confused as I typed because I was thinking struct in my head!

Comment: sizeof looks at the type of the expression. st is of type "pointer to struct retValue". \*st is of type "struct retValue" (* is the pointer dereferencing operator). Therefore, the type of the expression is "struct retValue" and it is the size of that type which the compiler will evaluate the sizeof-statement to.

Comment: Argument evaluation has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is the declaration/definition of the structure type and not the definition of an object of such a class. By the time you reach the `malloc`, a declaration/definition will have been encountered by the compiler, you'd hit a compiler error otherwise.

The fact that `sizeof` does not evaluate its operands is a side-issue.

A minor nit: remember that we **need** parentheses when we supply type names to `sizeof` as in:

```
sizeof(struct retValue);
```

and not in case of objects, we simply do:

```
sizeof *st;
```

See the standard:

> **6.5.3 Unary operators Syntax**

```
unary-expression:
[...]
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, `sizeof` is an operator, and doesn't evaluate its argument.  That can lead to "interesting" effects, that someone new to C does not necessarily anticipate.  I mentioned that in more detail in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2018786#2018786) to the "Strangest language feature" question.