# Problems getting int from void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm building a tiny linked list library for the purposes of self-enrichment, which has forced me to deal with a problem I'm nearly at a loss to explain. Take the following example, and assume that `new_item->data` is a void pointer inside a typedef struct:

```
int *data = malloc(sizeof(int));
*data = 42;
MY_LIST *new_item = malloc(sizeof(*new_item));
new_item->data = &data;

// prints what looks like a memory address
printf(
    "data: %i\n",
    *((int *) new_item->data)
);

//prints 42
int data2 = *((int *) new_item->data);
printf(
    "data2: %i\n",
    *((int *) data2)
);
```

As far as my (probably derelict) brain can tell, in both cases I'm using the same cast statement - `*((int *) new_item->data)` - to derive the integer from its container. Yet when I use it inline inside of printf, I get a memory address instead. What am I misunderstanding about this?

Comment: Welcome in the pointer hell.

Comment: adjust your _data_ assignment to `new_item->data = data;`

Comment: Shouldn't `MY_LIST *new_item = malloc(sizeof(*new_item));` be `MY_LIST *new_item = malloc(sizeof(new_item));`?  `sizeof(new_item)`, not `sizeof(*new_item)`?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: No, because new_item is a pointer - I want to allocate enough memory for the type which the pointer points to.

Comment: @sudowned So `new_item` is a pointer to a pointer to a structure.  Got it.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Nope, it's just a pointer to a structure. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178470/defining-a-structure-in-c-with-malloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem.

```
new_item->data = &data;
```

It `data` is pointing to the address of the pointer (pointer to pointer). `data` is already a pointer.

Make it following

```
new_item->data = data;
```

In the following case

```
//prints 42
int data2 = *((int *) new_item->data);
printf(
    "data2: %i\n",
    *((int *) data2) //You are dereferencing the pointer,
);
```

You are dereferencing the pointer that is why it prints 42.

In this case

```
// prints what looks like a memory address
printf(
    "data: %i\n",
    *((int *) new_item->data)
);
```

You are dereferncing `&data` which is stored in `new_item->data` which is now pointing to `data`. That is why it is printing an address. To get 42, dereference it again.

Comment: Good catch on the reference, though... I don't even know why I did that in the first place. The force is not with me tonight.