# How to correctly initialize an event

Tags: c++, ros2

I'm a student and currently experimenting with the QoS-settings in ROS 2. I'm trying to implement the (RMW_EVENT_REQUESTED_DEADLINE_MISSED) event.

First I declare the subscription and event:

```
static const rmw_subscription_t sub1
{
    "sub1", (void *) "gets deadline missed",  "topic1"
};
static const rmw_event_t deadline_missed =
{
    "event 1" , (void *) "deadline missed", RMW_EVENT_REQUESTED_DEADLINE_MISSED
};
```

After that I try to initialize the event:

```
rmw_subscription_event_init(deadline_missed, sub1, RMW_EVENT_REQUESTED_DEADLINE_MISSED);
```

But I get an error ( No matching function for call to 'rmw_subscription_event_init')

The program suggests me to change my subscription and event declaration to:

```
static const rmw_subscription_t *const sub1
{
    "sub1", (void *) "gets deadline missed",  "topic1"
};
static rmw_event_t *const deadline_missed =
{
       "event 1" , (void *) "deadline missed", RMW_EVENT_REQUESTED_DEADLINE_MISSED
};
```

But then I get the following error (Excess elements in scalar initializer).

How do I fix this problem and which of those 2 cases is the best?
Or is there a completely other way of creating this event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`rmw_subscription_event_init` takes pointers as argument so you need to pass the memory adress of your objects `rmw_subscription_t`and `rmw_event_t`  :

`rmw_subscription_event_init(&deadline_missed, &sub1, RMW_EVENT_REQUESTED_DEADLINE_MISSED);`

You can also change the definition of `sub1` and `deadline_missed` to be pointers (as you suggested), but in that case you need to properly initialize the pointers to your structs. I recommand reading these [excellent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709929/how-to-initialize-a-pointer-to-a-struct-in-c) for more information.