# Compiling errors in C while creating a dynamic array inside data structure

Tags: c

So I have a program I am working on to implement a B-Tree, but I am getting a few annoying compiling errors. The B-Tree structure was working, but I have to implement a functionality to accept the order of the tree as an input, which is causing some problems. The errors I have are:

Prelim.c:29:38: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘=’ token

Prelim.c:26:6: error: flexible array member not at end of struct

The code affected is:

```
struct bTreeNode {                      
    int count;                      
    int value[];                                   // This is line 26

    struct bTreeNode *branch[]; 

    struct bTreeNode *branch[order - 1] = malloc(sizeof(order));   // This is line 29
    int value[order - 1] = malloc(sizeof(order));

};
```

My question is two parts: First, why are these errors occurring, and second, How can I implement this idea properly? (I can provide additional code if needed and order is declared as a global variable). Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can't allocate structure in structure definition. Also allocation syntax which you have used is totally wrong. learn [how to use malloc for dynamically allocate structures.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177391/allocating-memory-for-a-structure-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

1. "why are these errors occurring"

   In your code, `branch` is an array of `bTreeNode` pointers, so you must tell compiler the length of `branch`.
   try this code:

   ```
   #define ORDER 10; // hard-coded
   struct bTreeNode {
       int count;
       int value[ORDER];
       struct bTreeNode *branch[ORDER - 1]; 
       int value[ORDER - 1];
   };
   ```

   And you can not use any functions in `struct bTreeNode` definition.
2. " How can I implement this idea properly"

   Flexible array is a good idea, try `struct bTreeNode *branch[0]`, and allocate memory later. Sorry for my ugly english. ^_^

Comment: Flexible array members do not need to be declared as `[0]` but just as `[]` but they should be the last member of the `struct` (and the only flexible one).

Comment: Disagree, if flexible array is declared as `[]`, MinGW would tell you "error: flexible array member in otherwise empty struct". However, `[0]` has compatibility.

Comment: Flexible array are C99 only

Comment: Disagree again, I haven't seen any sentences like "**obsolete** flexible array" or "**deprecate** flexible array " in C11 standard.

Comment: I just meant that they are not (yet) in the old C89 or ANSI-C standard.

Answer (score 0):

this declaration has a problem

```
struct bTreeNode *branch[order - 1] = malloc(sizeof(order));
```

the branch pointer is suppose to point at (order - 1) b-tree nodes, but you are allocating the memory size of order (which is probably an int, so it will return 4 bytes probably)
you need to allocate the memory of btreeNode times the order (number of btree nodes * order). try this..

```
struct bTreeNode *branch = malloc(sizeof(struct bTreeNode)*order);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a [flexible array member](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/), that is inside a `struct` an array without dimensions known at compile time. You can only have one of them, and it should be the last member of the `struct`:

```
struct bTreeNode {                      
  int count;                      
  int value[];     // flexible array member
};
```

<sup>flexible array members is an advanced feature of [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)</sup>

I'm guessing that you want your node to have arbitrary number of values and arbitrary number of sons. You need two flexible `struct` for that and you should use pointers.

```
// forward declarations
struct bTreeNode;
struct bTreeNumber;
struct bTreeSons;

struct bTreeNumber {
  unsigned valcount;
  int value[]; // actual dimension is valcount
};

struct bTreeSons {
   unsigned soncount;
   struct bTreeNode* ptrs[]; // actual dimension is soncount
};

struct bTreeNode {
  struct bTreeNumbers* numbers;
  struct bTreeSons* sons; 
};
```

Here is a function allocating an empty node with a given number of values and another number of sons

```
struct bTreeNode *make_node (unsigned nbval, unsigned nbsons)
{
   struct bTreeNumber* pnum = 
      malloc(sizeof(bTreeNumber)+nbval*sizeof(int));
   if (!pnum) { perror("malloc bTreeNumber"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   pnum->valcount = nbval;
   if (nbval>0) memset (pnum->value, 0, nbval*sizeof(int));
   struct bTreeSon* pson = 
      malloc(sizeof(bTreeSon)+nbsons*sizeof(struct bTreeNode*));
   if (!pson) { perror("malloc bTreeSon"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   pson->soncount = nbsons;
   for (unsigned ix=0; ix<nbsons; ix++) pson->ptrs[i] = NULL;
   struct bTreNode *pnode = malloc(sizeof(struct bTreeNode));
   if (!pnode) {perror("malloc bTreeNode"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE));
   pnode->numbers = pnum;
   pnode->sons = pson;
   return pnode;
 }
```

Alternatively you could decide that your nodes have a pointer to the numbers, and a flexible array member for sons (or vice versa)

```
 // alternatively
 struct bTreeNode {
   unsigned nbsons;
   struct bTreeNumber* numbers;
   struct bTreeNode* sons[]; // actual dimension is nbsons
 };
```

or even more "old-school" you could have the node know the number of sons and number of values, and keep pointers to (heap-allocated) arrays of them:

```
 // without flexible members
 struct bTreeNode {
    unsigned nbsons;
    unsigned nbvalues;
    int* pvalues; // point to an array of dimension nbvalues 
    struct bTreeNode** psons; // point to an array of dimension nbsons
 };
```